# Como pasar un parametro por NODEJS

Tags: nodejs, express, get

tengo este problema, quiero pasar un parametro como lo es el `htmlspecialchars($_GET["nombre"])` de php, pero no lo logro, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme:

```
app.get("/test/:valor", (req, res) => {
  const p = req.params.valor;
});
```

`const url = comps[p];`

La idea que tengo es recibir un numero (posición de un array), http://ejemplo.com/test/0
Logicamente no puedo usar la variable esa, pero como puedo hacer?

Edito: Quiero usar la misma plantilla, que extraiga los datos, y que acceda depende la url que ponga:

```
var http = require("http");
let fs = require("fs");

const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/test/:valor", (req, res) => {
  const p = req.params.valor;
  console.log(req.params.valor);
});
const comps = [
  /*0*/ "https://m.livesoccertv.com/es/match/",
  /*1*/ "https://m.livesoccertv.com/es/match/"
];

const url = comps[p];

const SCRAPING_URL = url;

(async () => {
  const response = await axios
    .get(SCRAPING_URL)
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  const results = [];
  const resultadoFinal = [];
  const title = [];

  if (response) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response);
    $("h2").each(function () {
      resultadoFinal.push($(this).text());
    });
    $("span.b_statline_number").each(function () {
      results.push($(this).text());
    });
    $("div[class='fll b_statline_center']").each(function () {
      title.push($(this).text());
    });

    //console.log(e);

    /*$("div").each(function (i, e) {
      title.push($(e).attr("data-timestamp"));
    });*/
  }
  const preResults = results.filter((data) => data !== "");
  //const predtResults = title.filter((data) => data !== undefined);

  const resultsFiltrados = [];
  //const resultsdtFiltrados = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    resultsFiltrados.push(
      `${preResults[0 + i * 2]} ${title[i]} ${preResults[1 + i * 2]}`
    );
  }
  /*for (i = 0; i <= f + 1; i++) {
    resultsdtFiltrados.push(`${predtResults[i]}`);
  }*/
  //create a server object:
  let handleRequest = (request, response) => {
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
    for (var x2a = 0; x2a <= 2; x2a++) {
      response.write("<html><body>" + resultadoFinal[x2a] + " <br />");
    }
    for (var x2 = 0; x2 <= 8; x2++) {
      response.write("" + resultsFiltrados[x2] + " <br /></body></html>");
    }
    response.end();
  };

  http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(8000);

  //the server object listens on port 8080
  function log(socket, data) {
    console.log(resultsFiltrados);
    socket.emit("message", resultsFiltrados);
  }
  //console.log(resultsdtFiltrados);
  console.log(resultsFiltrados);
})();
```

veo que no existe lo que quiero hacer...

Comment: Estás usando ```express```?

Comment: Si, correcto, no lo aclare, perdon.

Comment: Debería de estar funcionando perfectamente, que sale si haces un log? Algo cómo ```console.log(req.params)```?

Comment: `console.log(req.params.valor);  ReferenceError: req is not defined` porque lo estoy usandolo fuera de la funcion

Comment: A qué te refieres con *fuera de la función*? Si no está bajo el scope de la función no vas a poder acceder al request y por lo tanto no podrás acceder a los parametros de la URL.

Comment: ahi edite la pregunta, tal vez se entiende lo que quiero hacer

Comment: Hmmmm.... Ok, ya entiendo que está pasando. Tienes un problema de asincronía y de alcance (scope) de tu variable. `p` existe hasta que se haga un request, tendrías que inicializarla como una variable global  para que todo el código tenga acceso a ella y luego cuando llegue el `HTTP GET` modificar su valor. Sin embargo, esto noes lo mejor y creo que esto se puede hacer de una mejor manera, no entiendo la arquitectura que estás siguiendo. Esa IIFE que tienes al final del código que hace el scrapping, cada cuanto corre? Una única vez? Cada cuánto quieres hacer el scrapping?

Comment: Si quieres hacer el scrapping cuando se reciba algo a `ejemplo.com/test/0` te recomiendo meter la función dentro del handler de express. Es decir, debajo del `console.log(req.params.valor);`.

Comment: Por otro lado ya tienes tu servidor de express corriendo, podrías utilizarlo para dar la página que quieres dar con tu otro servidor y manejar el estado de tu aplicación con archivos, variables o una base de datos. De lo contrario vas a tener el problema de que el servidor se crea siempre con el valor default de `p` ya que el handler del servidor se configuraría con el valor que vea al principio y no cambiará ni con el request que llegue a tu servidor de express.

Comment: El scrapping se ejecuta una vez cuando se carga la web, yo lo que necesito es pasar la url (la cual es la que se le hace el scrap) mediante los parametros, asi poder cambiar mediante el link

Comment: En  ese caso necesitas unificar los recursos de ambos servidores... Tal vez con variables globales, de lo contrario lo que está dentro de la IIFE estará totalmente separado de la variable `p`

Comment: Pero tienes algun ejemplo o algo para tener de referencia?

Comment: Lastimosamente no tengo tiempo para ponerte un ejemplo y no creo que encuentres en ningún lado algo que se asemeje a lo que estás tratando de hacer. Mi recomendación final es que dejes de usar el módulo de `http` de node y solo utilices `express`, para que unifiques el código. Si haces algún avance postealo como pregunta (siempre y cuando difiera de esta) o actualiza esta misma pregunta y veré si puedo ayudarte con gusto.

Comment: intente de todo y no lo logre... Lo probe con variable globales, al menos como para ver si funciona, pero no se pudo, no creo que no exista lo que quiero hacer. No voy a crear 100 paginas con distintas urls, cuando puedo usar la misma, y cambiar el url dinamicamente.